# Можно ли как то воспользоваться классами css в PyQT?

Tags: css, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, pyside6

Я знаю, что можно делать что-то подобное:

```py
STYLE_SHEET = '''
QPushButton {
    background: #255983;
    font: bold 28px;
    color: #66B5FF;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #66B5FF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    color: #00E5FF;
    border-color: #00E5FF;
    background: #007AFF;
    outline: none;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но тут явно указаны названия элементов, для которых мы пишем css свойства. Можно ли тут использовать классы? И потом задавать для каждого элемента свой класс, вместо того чтобы, например, менять свойства для всех QPushButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в каком смысле вы используете класс, из контекста больше похоже на id.

Например, имя объекта кнопки myButton, то стиль задается так:

```
QPushButton#myButton {...}
```

Также вы можете наследовать кнопку и таким образом создать новый класс.
Стили для него создаются как и для библиотечных классов - с указанием имени

```
MyButtonClass {...}
```

Больше информации и подробности можно найти [вот тут](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Это как раз то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: А еще можно одно уточнение, в css есть такие вещи как transform, и его параметры как rotate(), scale(), также есть transition. В pyqt, когда я пытаюсь нечто подобное добавить, он начинает плеваться ошибками. Я так понимаю это здесь не поддерживается?

Comment: @Effex qt и pyqt имеют ограничения в поддержке css, надо смотреть документацию.